# Produce a string from a tuple

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am looking for a nice, efficient and pythonic way to go from something like this:

`('zone1', 'pcomp110007')`

to this:

`'ZONE 1, PCOMP 110007'`

without the use of `regex` if possible (unless it does make a big difference that is..). So turn every letter into uppercase, put a space between letters and numbers and join with a comma.

What i wrote is the following:

```
tags = ('zone1', 'pcomp110007')


def sep(astr):
    chars = ''.join([x.upper() for x in astr if x.isalpha()])
    nums = ''.join([x for x in astr if x.isnumeric()])
    return chars + ' ' + nums

print(', '.join(map(sep, tags)))
```

Which does produce the desired result but looks a bit too much for the task.

**The tuple might vary in length but the numbers are always going to be at the end of each string.**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My thoughts:

Keep `sep` a normal function like it is in your original code for readability / maintenance, but also leverage `re` as suggested in Abdou's answer.

```
import re
tags = ('zone1', 'pcomp110007')

def sep(astr):
    alpha, num = re.match('([^\d]+)([\d]+)', astr).groups()
    return '{} {}'.format(alpha.upper(), num) 

print(', '.join(map(sep, tags)))
```

Edit: Note that if you prefer, I think it would also be reasonable to just return:

```
return alpha.upper() + ' ' + num
```

Or older style string formatting:

```
return '%s %s' %(alpha.upper(), num)
```

Whatever you're most comfortable with.

Answer (score 6):

Regex does help. This should always work:

```
import re
tags = ('zone1', 'pcomp110007')

def sep(s):
    word = re.split(r'\d', s)[0]
    return word.upper() + " " + s[len(word):]

print(', '.join(map(sep, tags)))
```

Comment: `format()` would look cleaner: `return '{} {}'.format(word.upper(), s[len(word):])`

Answer (score 3):

Using `re`:

```
import re

tupl = ('zone1', 'pcomp110007')

", ".join(map(lambda x: " ".join(re.findall('([A-Z]+)([0-9])+',x.upper())[0]), tupl))

#'ZONE 1, PCOMP 7'
```

Comment: No need for `list()`.

Comment: Oh thanks! I did not know that `join` could be applied to `map` objects.

Comment: @Abdou it accepts any iterable yielding strings -- even generator expressions.

Answer (score 2):

I think your way is pythonic enough. If you want to make it "more functional style", then you can use this one:

```
sep = lambda s: " ".join((filter(str.isalpha, s).upper(), filter(str.isdigit, s)))
print(', '.join(map(sep, tags)))
```

Updated: It's Python3 version, for Python2 you need to use `upper` for `s`, not for `filter`.

Comment: i like the use of `filter()`

Comment: It is missing a closing parenthesis and the `upper()` has to go to the `s` not to the filter. this doesn't actually work thought.

Comment: "> It is missing a closing parenthesis"
Yep, sorry, fixed.
"> the upper() has to go to the s"
It depends on the version of the python. I use py3.

Answer (score 1):

Here is my stab:

```
>>> for i, s in enumerate(tags[1][::-1]):
...   if s.isalpha():
...     print (tags[1][:i], tags[1][i:])
        break
... 
pcomp1 10007
```

I walk back thru the string to find first alpha, then split and print each side (alpha, numeric).  I left out conversion to upper case which is easy to add

Answer (score 1):

A recursive solution:

```
def non_regex_split(s,i=0):
    if len(s) == i:
        return s
    try:
        return '%s %d' %(s[:i], int(s[i:]))
    except:
        return non_regex_split(s,i+1)

', '.join(non_regex_split(s).upper() for s in tags)
```

Answer (score 1):

Thank you all for the answers. I timed a couple here are the results and the timing script:

```
setup = '''
import re
tags = ('zone1', 'pcomp110007')


def sepListComp(astr):
    res = ''.join([x.upper() for x in astr if x.isalpha()]), ''.join([x for x in astr if x.isnumeric()])
    return '{} {}'.format(*res)


def sepFilter(astr):
    res = ''.join(filter(str.isalpha, astr.upper())), ''.join(filter(str.isdigit, astr.upper()))
    return '{} {}'.format(*res)


def sepRe1(astr):
    alpha, num = re.match('([^\d]+)([\d]+)', astr).groups()
    return '{} {}'.format(alpha.upper(), num)


def sepRe2(s):
    word = re.split(r'\d', s)[0]
    return word.upper() + " " + s[len(word):]


def Recursive(s,i=0):
    if len(s) == i:
        return s
    try:
        return '%s %d' %(s[:i], int(s[i:]))
    except:
        return Recursive(s,i+1)
'''
from timeit import timeit

print('sepListComp:', timeit(stmt='", ".join(map(sepListComp, tags))', setup=setup, number=100000))
print('sepFilter:', timeit(stmt='", ".join(map(sepFilter, tags))', setup=setup, number=100000))
print('sepRe1:', timeit(stmt='", ".join(map(sepRe1, tags))', setup=setup, number=100000))
print('sepRe2:', timeit(stmt='", ".join(map(sepRe2, tags))', setup=setup, number=100000))
print('sepRecursive:', timeit(stmt='", ".join(Recursive(s).upper() for s in tags)', setup=setup, number=100000))
```

- *sepListComp*: 1.0487s
- *sepFilter*: 1.1690s
- *sepRe1*: 0.8751s
- *sepRe2*: 0.8332s
- *sepRecursive*: 3.4539s

So `regex` wins. The results vary alot though. Any comments or suggestions on the timing are greatly appreciated.